# PHP manipulating multidimensional array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have a result set as an array from a database that looks like:

```
array (
    0 => array (
        "a" => "something"
        "b" => "something"
        "c" => "something"
    )
    1 => array (
        "a" => "something"
        "b" => "something"
        "c" => "something"
    )
    2 => array (
        "a" => "something"
        "b" => "something"
        "c" => "something"
    )
)
```

How would I apply a function to replace the values of an array only on the array key with b? Normally I would just rebuild a new array with a foreach loop and apply the function if the array key is b, but I'm not sure if it's the best way. I've tried taking a look at many array functions and it seemed like array_walk_recursive is something I might use, but I didn't have luck in getting it to do what I want. If I'm not describing it well enough, basically I want to be able to do as the code below does:

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($result as $key => $value)
{
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2)
    {
        $arr[$key][$key2] = ($key2 == 'b' ? $this->_my_method($value2) : $value2);
    }    
}
```

Should I stick with that, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php):

If you have PHP >= 5.3.0 (for [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)):

```
array_walk_recursive($result, function (&$item, $key) {
    if ($key == 'b') {
        $item = 'the key is b!';
    }
});
```

Otherwise something like:

```
function _my_method(&$item, $key) {
    if ($key == 'b') {
        $item = 'the key is b!';
    }
}
array_walk_recursive($result, '_my_method');
```

Comment: Thanks, I had already tried array_walk_recursive as I said above, but it didn't work. Apparently I forgot to place the ampersand before the $item param! Working now.

Comment: Yup, easy mistake to make. Quoting the manual: `If funcname needs to be working with the actual values of the array, specify the first parameter of funcname as a reference. Then, any changes made to those elements will be made in the original array itself.`

Answer (score 0):

Untested but I think this will work.

```
function replace_b (&$arr)
{
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v)
    {
        if ($k == 'b')
        {
            /* Do something */
        }
        if (is_array($v)
        {
            replace_b($arr[$k]);
        }
    }
}
```

The function will move through an array checking the keys for `b`. If the key points to an array it recursively follows it down.

Comment: @Jacob: I'm unfamiliar with the exact syntax of `array_walk_recursive` and didn't bother looking it up. Typing this was faster.

Comment: I wonder it is the performance difference between using `array_walk_recursive` vs. loop + calling the same function. Just like @JacobRelkin, I am used to doing it the loop + calling the same function, and it has worked just fine in the past.

Answer (score 0):

use `array_walk_recursive`  [documented here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

```
$replacer = function($x) {return "I used to be called $x";}; //put what you need here
$replaceB = function(&$v, $k) use ($replacer) {if ($k === 'b') $v = $replacer($v);};

array_walk_recursive($arr, $replaceB);
```

The `replacer` function might be overkill.  You can replace it with a literal or anything you like.

Comment: I am not sure why someone decided to downvote your answer - it did work for me. I would however recommend cleaning it up, ie mentioning that the key is to pass $v as reference and changing the code to print the start and end values, and of course make it easier to read (not using unnecessary lambda functions or additional logic like `$k == 'b'` ).